# Why won't WIndows XP recognize my network adapter?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, network-adapter

I have used Everest to determine that my network adapter is a `RealTek RTL8139/810x Fast Ethernet Adapter` and installed the appropriate driver. But I can't see any Local Area Connection in my Network Connections.

**I Downloaded driver from [here](http://152.104.125.41/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=2&PNid=14&PFid=6&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&SortByDesc=0) but installation doesn't make a LAN in My Network Connections**

Comment: start back in the device manager, before going to the net stuff in XP. Is the device installed proper, drivers showing? any yellow flags or unknowns?

Comment: @Psycogeek: unknowns. It have yellow flag

Comment: @Psycogeek:It found but can't install

Comment: question edited

Comment: @Psycogeek: trying...

Comment: @Psycogeek: It worked. Make an answer

Comment: It would be better If you write the answer with the steps you used to do it. I am not in Xp now to write it properly step by step

Comment: @Psycogeek: I'm Preparing an XP computer but I'm in 7. but I write it step by step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks to [Psycogeek](https://superuser.com/users/98855/psycogeek), here's step by step solution:

First in Start Menu right click on `My Computer` and click on `Manage`.
At the left Tree View click on `Device Manager`.
at the center Tree View on `Other devices` right click on your `Ethernet adapter` and click `Uninstall`.

after Uninstall at upper menu on `Action` Menu click on `Scan for hardware change` and when your `Ethernet adapter` recognized wait for windows prepare to install the driver.

at first page of installation click on `no thanks`(because you have no Internet Connection!) and `Next`
after that click on `Advanced` and `Next`
and then click on `Don't Search` and `Next` and at next page chose `Network Adapter` from list. and `Next` then Chose the `Manufacturer` of your `Network Adapter` and the `Network Adapter` type.and `Next`. If you see a message box click yes and wait for your driver to install and finally you have your driver :)